# Finding the request is to Script or a .Net request

Tags: javascript, c#, code-injection

In my sample application if an URL is clicked I will get two requests.

One is for the .Net application and another is for JavaScript in that application.

I had injected my code in all the functions of that application. In runtime can I find if that request is Java script or a .NET request.

./Rahul

Answer (score 0):

You can check it via

```
Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"]
```

Comment: No.. This does not work. It makes the program to crash.!